# Nuxt child: parent route works incorrectly

Tags: nuxt.js, vue-router, router, nested-routes

This is my files tree:

```
pages/
-index.vue   (1)
-index/
--_id.vue    (2)
```

I expect:

- if route is `mydomain.com` -> render `index.vue (1)` only
- if route is `mydomain.com/foo` -> render `_id.vue (2)` inside `index.vue (1)`

When I don't have a parameter for the child component I want the Nuxt child not to render at all, but Nuxt render it with `id` value of `undefined`. Vue router do it correctly.

This is JSFiddle like Nuxt behavior: https://jsfiddle.net/maxmets/95ctse8d/ (line 16 `path: '/:id?'`)

This is JSFiddle I want (Vue router): https://jsfiddle.net/maxmets/rvmxg2f7/ (line 16 `path: '/:id'`)

The different is only in `?` symbol. When Nuxt automatically create object of routes it add `?`
How to make the Nuxt router work as correctly as the Vue router?

Answer (score 2):

You could try this [Nested Route](https://nuxtjs.org/guides/features/file-system-routing#nested-routes) method:

```
pages/
-index.vue   (1)
-index/
--_id.vue    (2)
--_index.vue    (3)
```

In `index/index.vue`, you can just render empty template

```
<template>
  <div></div>
</template>
```

This maybe not be the cleanest way to do, but it should get the job  done.

### OR

But if you choose to define your own router, you can check out [Nuxt Router Extra Module](https://github.com/nuxt-community/router-extras-module)